# "parents().filter" returns undefined if data-attribut equals zero

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

This works fine, except when then data-* is equal to "0", can anyone explain why.

If I access the attribute directly it works fine, for example $("#Floor0").data("floor") returns 0 as expected.
But if I use the filter-function to find a parent with data-floor, it will not work if the parents data-floor="0".
If I change the data-floor="0" to data-floor="00", or any other value, it will work.

[Link to JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o05kz7uf/)

```js
console.log($("#Floor2").data("floor"));
console.log($("#Floor1").data("floor"));
console.log($("#Floor0").data("floor"));


Test('a2');
Test('a1');
Test('a0');


function Test(id){

  var FloorId = $("#"+id).parents().filter(function() {
    return $(this).data("floor");
  }).eq(0);
    console.log(FloorId.data("floor"));
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div data-floor="0" id="Floor0">
    <div>
      <label>0</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="a0" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-floor="1" id="Floor1">
    <div>
      <label>1</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="a1" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-floor="2" id="Floor2">
    <div>
      <label>2</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="a2" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
```

Comment: A _string_ containing `0` should not be considered falsy in JS, but I am guessing `.data()` is probably converting this to a numeric value(?) Can you explain what exactly you are trying to “filter” here though? Can’t make much sense of this example, in regard to that.

Comment: I am trying to determine what floor-number a checkbox belongs to. In my real code there are a lot more checkboxes and other stuff for each floor, so in order to minimize the need to repeat the floor-number on each control i tried this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `closest()` instead `parents()` with a selector to avoid loop here (its faster): so you could use parents with same selector than closest, but parents will test all parents, closest stops when the first is found.

```js
Test("a0");
Test("a1");
Test("a2");

function Test(id) {
  var FloorId = $("#" + id).closest("div[id^=Floor]");
  //parents too
  //var FloorId = $("#" + id).parents("div[id^=Floor]");
  console.log(FloorId.data("floor"));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div data-floor="0" id="Floor0">
    <div>
      <label>0</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="a0" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-floor="1" id="Floor1">
    <div>
      <label>1</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="a1" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-floor="2" id="Floor2">
    <div>
      <label>2</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="a2" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. I had som initial problems because I dont have id's on the Floor-divs in my real code, but I adjusted your code and tried this : $("#"+id).closest("div[data-floor]") and that seems to work whitout id's.

Answer (score 2):

While there are better solutions (already accepted), the *reason* your initial code didn't work is because:

- jquery's `.data("..")` will attempt to coerce the data to the relevant type.  
  So `data-floor="0"` returns (numeric) `0`
- .filter() with `return 0` (not return "0") is the same as `return false` so excludes the item from the filter.

Without making any fundamental changes to your code, you *could* change `.data(..)` to `.attr("data-..")` as `.attr()` will always return a string.

Updated snippet:

```js
console.log($("#Floor2").data("floor"));
console.log($("#Floor1").data("floor"));
console.log($("#Floor0").data("floor"));


Test('a2');
Test('a1');
Test('a0');


function Test(id){

  var FloorId = $("#"+id).parents().filter(function() {
    return $(this).attr("data-floor");
  }).eq(0);
    console.log(FloorId.data("floor"));
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div data-floor="0" id="Floor0">
    <div>
      <label>0</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="a0" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-floor="1" id="Floor1">
    <div>
      <label>1</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="a1" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-floor="2" id="Floor2">
    <div>
      <label>2</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="a2" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
```